# Cannot start LXC container: failed creating cgroups

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, container

I am using LXC (Linux Container) 1.0.6 on a Ubuntu 14.04 64bit Virtual Machine trying to build HTTP service in a container. I have trouble starting the container:

```
$ sudo lxc-start -n test1
lxc-start: failed creating cgroups
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'test1'
lxc-start: The container failed to start.
lxc-start: Additional information can be obtained by setting the --logfile and --logpriority options.
```

All dependencies are installed prior to creating container:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcap-dev automake bridge-utils debootstrap
```

Cgroup status:

```
$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
2:name=systemd:/user/1000.user/c1.session
```

The container is based on ubuntu template with:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.100.1/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.100.0
lxc.network.veth.pair = vethtest1
```

bridge is brought up using:

```
$ sudo brctl addbr lxcbr0
$ sudo brctl addif lxcbr0 eth0
$ sudo ifconfig lxcbr0 192.168.100.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

I used to be able to at least start container with similar config before on another machine, this time it is a new instance, and I never run into problem with cgroups.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe apparmor is messing around. Add this to the container definition. In my system it is in */var/lib/lxc/containername/config*

```
lxc.aa_allow_incomplete = 1
```